# Do indexes need to be rebuilt when restoring a database with existing indexes?

Tags: database, postgresql

I removed some indexes on a very large table and realized I needed them. Instead of adding them back concurrently, which would take a very long time, I was wondering if I could just do restore using a database copy that was taken before the indexes were removed?

Comment: MySQL or Postgresql and what version?

Comment: sorry it is for postgres 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "database copy" you mean a copy of the **Postgres** DB directory at file level (with Postgres not running to get a consistent state), then **yes**, such a snapshot includes everything, indexes too. You could copy that back on file level, and then start Postgres - falling back to the previous state, of course.

If, OTOH, you mean a backup with the standard Postgres tools `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall`, then **no**, indexes are not included physically. Just the instructions to build them. It would not make sense to include huge junks of functionally dependent values. Building them from restored data may be about as fast.

Either way, you could not add back an index from an older snapshot to a live DB anyway, after changes to the table have been made. That's a logically  impossible. Then there is no alternative to rebuilding the index one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer for MySQL. You tagged your question with both [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) so I don't know which one you really use.

If your backup was a physical backup made with a backup solution like Percona XtraBackup or MySQL Enterprise Backup, it will include the indexes, so restoring it will be quicker.

If your backup was a logical backup made with `mysqldump` or `mydumper`, then the backup includes only data. Restoring it will have to rebuild the indexes anyway. It will not save any time.

If you made the mistake of making a "backup" only by copying files out of the data directory, those are sort of like the physical backup, but unless you copied the files while the MySQL Server was shut down, the backup is probably not viable.